# Marker and Circle Marker have different visual position

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 18);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var marker1 = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]);
var FeatureGroup = L.geoJson([],{
  pointToLayer: function(f,l){
    return L.circleMarker(l);
  }
});
//Many features
var index = 4000; 
var yindex= 0;
while(index){
y= "51.5"+index
y=y*1
FeatureGroup.addData({
  type:"Feature",
  properties: {},
  geometry:{ type:"Point", coordinates:[-0.09, y]}
});
index--;
}



//var Coordinates = marker1.getLatLng();
var feature = {
  type:"Feature",
  properties: {},
  geometry:{ type:"Point", coordinates:[marker1.getLatLng().lng, marker1.getLatLng().lat]}
};
//var circleMarker = L.circleMarker(Coordinates);
FeatureGroup.addLayer(marker1);

map.addLayer(FeatureGroup);

setTimeout(function(){
//remove the marker 
FeatureGroup.removeLayer(marker1._leaflet_id);
//adds the circle marker
FeatureGroup.addData(feature);
},2000);
```

```css
.map{
width: auto;
height: 350px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id=map class="map"></div>
```

Clicking on the map adds a marker at the position X, Y to a `FeatureGroup`, then removes the marker to be replaced by a `circlemarker` in the same positions X, Y.

The `circleMarker` in the `FeatureGroup` appears with the correct coordinates but visually is located in another position.

I use Leaflet version 1.3.1

Comment: In a totally different position, or just offset by a constant amount?

Comment: Please make sure you include enough details and code in your question for people to be able to understand and reproduce your issue. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and in particular about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provides some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> The `circleMarker` in the `FeatureGroup` appears with the correct coordinates but visually is located in another position.

You are probably fooled by an "optical illusion", due to the fact the Marker only **points** to the given coordinates, with its icon positioned **above** this location, whereas the Circle Marker is **centered around** the same location.

You can see the effect by simultaneously displaying both the Marker and the Circle Marker:

[image: Screenshot Marker and Circle Marker on same position]

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 18);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var marker1 = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]);

var FeatureGroup = L.geoJson([], {
  pointToLayer: function(f, l) {
    return L.circleMarker(l);
  }
});
var feature = {
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {},
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [marker1.getLatLng().lng, marker1.getLatLng().lat]
  }
};
FeatureGroup.addLayer(marker1);
//adds the circle marker
FeatureGroup.addData(feature);

map.addLayer(FeatureGroup);
```

```css
.map {
  width: auto;
  height: 350px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id=map class="map"></div>
```